# Is it possible to upload iPhone apps to iPhone on an expired dev certificate?

Tags: iphone

As the title says, is it possible to upload iPhone apps to iPhone on an expired dev certificate? Do we need to extend our dev certificate once it's expired and pay another 99$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to renew your dev certificate and your provisions to upload apps from Xcode to stock iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can go though a [lengthy process to crack xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-real-iphone-device/4180498#4180498) so you'll be able to "upload" iphone apps to your jailbroken iphone with no certificate.

But to upload to Apple Store, your only bet is paying $99 per year, since the beginning of i